# How to access the profile photo of a user in a Lightning community?

Tags: lightning, chatter, community

I am trying to make an application that would present chatter content to be displayed in a lightning community.

What would be the best way to display the profile photo of the user who posted this question/comment in chatter? 
And also is it possible to access this photo in an anonymous community?

I am able to get the URL of the `smallphotourl` through a hack-ish way of the user who created the chatter message. But, this url is using the salesforce internal domain (ex. `na35.salesforce.com/profilephoto/<UserID>/T`) so that would not work inside a lightning community.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should not create any issue as long as you use User `smallPhotURL` or `fullPhotoURL`.

The same approach is being used in this [Lightning Utility Pack](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000000qDmjEAE) Appexchange Lightning Tasklist component.They are using the `fullPhotoURL` field

In our production, that URL looks like:-

> https://trivia.na2.content.force.com/profilephoto/72928000000CxmT/F

Comment: So they are using an Apex Controller to get the User object and get the value for `smallphotourl`? 
And you can display this directly in a lightning community?

Comment: Yes, field is accessible though controller only. I checked their component and the URL I had in my User.

Comment: This is the url I get when right clicking on the image and inspecting in a lightning community: 
https://erocheleau-dev1-developer-edition.na35.force.com/indexlesstemplates/profilephoto/72941000000TaLv/M

Comment: This is the url I get when getting the smallphotourl of the user who posted the chatter content:
https://c.na35.content.force.com/profilephoto/72941000000TaLv/T
(First one works, this one redirects to the login page).

Comment: I just checked the component in community the url seems like `/sfsites/c/profilephoto/72928000000CxmT/F`. @EtienneRocheleau

Comment: Thank you, yes I think I stumbled on the same thing while messing around with urls:
The correct URL to access a profilephoto anywhere seems to be:
`/profilephoto/72941000000TaLv/T`
The relative path seems to be able to resolve to the right domain.

Answer (score 2):

After some more digging around and investigation and help from @Ashwani:

The correct url to use in any case, seems to be a relative URL built from the smallphotourl field:

`/profilephoto/72941000000TaLv/T`

This is an example of an `<img src=` that would work both in lightning communities and in a visualforce page.

As a side note, if the user chose to not make his photo public on chatter: (Profile > Edit your chatter photo > Check/uncheck "Show my photo on publicly accessible pages")
This url will resolve to a placeholder photo from Salesforce. Which is neat.