# Chatter images of Custom Profile's users

Tags: chatter

Is there a way to see the chatter images of Custom Profile's users on Salesforce. I dont need the photo URL (SmallPhotoUrl or FullPhotoUrl) but need to view the images of users under Custom Profile.
I cant create a VF Page to display the Chatter images. Is there a standard Salesforce way to view the chatter images of custom profile's user.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like it, the url you need to use seems to be a relative one built from the smallphotourl field:

```
/profilephoto/ID/T
```

There is a similar question that was posted on the site:

[How to access the profile photo of a user in a Lightning community?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/153530/how-to-access-the-profile-photo-of-a-user-in-a-lightning-community)